# Java EE and Cobol integration

Tags: jakarta-ee, cobol

I have a lot of standalone Cobol programs, I would like to integrate them into a Java EE ecosystem. It would be beautifull if there's a way to put all those Cobol programs behind a RESTFul interface. Does anyone already stumbled in an integration problem like this? Suggestions are very appreciated, I'm surfing the web to make my opinion.

Update: COBOL programs are run on a simple Linux machine, as batch or as Apache's cgi.

Comment: Where do the COBOL programs execute?  For example, this is relatively easy with z/OS and CICS.  We need to know more about your environment in order to answer your question.

Comment: Hello. COBOL programs are run by command line. There is nothing like an AS400 to run them.

Comment: "By command line" does not provide sufficient information to help you.  Please tell us about the OS and so forth.  Is this Windows and IIS? Is this Linux and Apache?

Comment: You're right. When I say "by command line" I mean that COBOL programs are run on a simple Linux machine, as batch or as Apache's cgi. I also update my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You should first design the functional infrastructure:

- how do you want to start the Cobol programs: a simple RESTful URL or a Human Interface?
- should the response only say that the program was started and another request would be necessary to get the result (with an unique identifier), or if programs run quickly, will first response contain the result from the command.

Then, you will just have to build a Java EE application that build command line parameters for external programs and (a)synchronously run them.